# Yii Caching for site controller/pages

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to cache every page that uses the SiteController. In the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.page) it says to add `public function filters()` into your controller to have it cache all actions.

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Declares class-based actions.
     */
     public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'COutputCache',
                'duration'=>1000,
                'varyByParam'=>array('id'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

However, after adding this, I am not seeing a decrease in page load. Am I missing something? I also have **not** added anything to my `main.php configuration file`. Is this an issue? Thanks!

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Declares class-based actions.
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
            'captcha'=>array(
                'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
                'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
            ),
            // page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
            // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
            'page'=>array(
                'class'=>'CViewAction',
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * This is the default 'index' action that is invoked
     * when an action is not explicitly requested by users.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
        // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'



        $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * This is the action to handle external exceptions.
     */
    public function actionError()
    {
        if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
        {
            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
                echo $error['message'];
            else
                $this->render('error', $error);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the contact page
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model=new ContactForm;
        if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
            if($model->validate())
            {
                $headers="From: {$model->email}\r\nReply-To: {$model->email}";
                mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$model->subject,$model->body,$headers);
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
                $this->refresh();
            }
        }
        $this->render('contact',array('model' => $model));
    }

    /**
     * Displays the login page
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $model=new LoginForm;

        // if it is ajax validation request
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }

        // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
            // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
            if($model->validate() && $model->login())
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('login',array('model' => $model));
    }

    /**
     * Logs out the current user and redirect to homepage.
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::app()->user->logout();
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable caching you need add something similar to the code below in main.php components demanding on you caching system db, file etc.

```
'cache'=>array(
'class'=>'system.caching.CDbCache',
        'connectionID'=>'db',
        'autoCreateCacheTable'=>false,
        'cacheTableName'=>'cache',
    ),
```