# Caching in yii for goods site

Tags: php, caching, yii

But i'm new to the caching technique. After reading [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview) (and following), and some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117101/yii-caching-for-site-controller-pages?rq=1) i still of little clue how to use it.

I need to apply caching for the CMS/CRM site we developed. The application/website is a mix of web shop and client order processing, how to make it optimized? What cache components is optimal to use?

The **typical user request** (the main concern for caching) would be to [assortment/goods grid page](http://tarex.ru/assortment/index) with ability to filter goods by category, make, manufacturer, article and so on.

**My concept** is that it's not possible to predict each user's behaviour as to what kind of options/filters he'll impose on given data. So how could caching be applied? Please, correct me if it's not so. Users might be logged in or not.

I've set in **main.php** the `cache` setting in components:

```
'components'=>array(
    'cache'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.caching.COutputCache',
             'connectionID'=>'db',
             'autoCreateCacheTable'=>false,
             'cacheTableName'=>'cache',
            ),
 ...
```

I've added **caching setting** into `filters()` of `AssortmentController`:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        array(
            'COutputCache',
            'duration'=>1000,
            'varyByParam'=>array('id'),
        ),
    );
}
```

1. Am i missing something apart from these two pieces of code? Should i use `beginCache` and `endCache` somewhere in view file or in layout file, where if so?
2. But suppose i want to use also CFileCache? Should/could i define it in components/cache array along with COutputCache that is already defined?
3. In this [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview) COutputCache is not mentioned, how to properly configure it?
4. But still there might be more GET parameters (apart from `id`) like *Assortment[title]*, *Assortment[article]* , *Assortment[groupCategory]*? 
   Should i add them as well?

   `'varyByParam'=>array('id', 'Assortment[title]', 'Assortment[article]' , 'Assortment[groupCategory]')`

Any corrections, docs' links, guidelines would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

1. You dont need to do anything additional to begin caching. From the question, it looks like you are using DbCaching - so you should be able to see records in the cache table. BeginCache/EndCache can be helpful if you want to cache only parts of the view / output.

To create cache for particular views add this: 'COutputCache + view', (this means only 'view' action will be cached)

2. You may use multiple Cache either by defining a cacheId and referring it to it in beginCache $this->beginCache('name', array('cacheID' => 'filecache')).
3. COutputCache is referred here (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/COutputCache).
4. Only the params inside the varyByParams will be considered for cache key. /products/view/1/some/param AND /products/view/1/another/param will be served from the same cache

If you have additional params that will add / be part of the caching you need to add them.